# Facing issue "Caused by: org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize" while upgrading from Helidon 2.5.4 to 3.2.0

Tags: helidon

We are trying to migrate from Helidon 2.5.4 to Helidon 3.2.0.
We have observed that some of our tests are failing with below error,
`Caused by: org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.doDeserialize(SerializationHelper.java:231) at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.deserialize(SerializationHelper.java:287) at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.clone(SerializationHelper.java:75) at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableJavaType$SerializableMutabilityPlan.deepCopyNotNull(SerializableJavaType.java:44) at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableJavaType$SerializableMutabilityPlan.deepCopyNotNull(SerializableJavaType.java:35) at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.MutableMutabilityPlan.deepCopy(MutableMutabilityPlan.java:45) at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.JavaType.getReplacement(JavaType.java:77) at org.hibernate.type.internal.ConvertedBasicTypeImpl.replace(ConvertedBasicTypeImpl.java:329) at org.hibernate.type.TypeHelper.replace(TypeHelper.java:88) at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.copyValues(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:493) at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsDetached(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:384) at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:176) at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:76) at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:107) at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:828) ... 97 more Caused by: java.io.InvalidClassException: filter status: REJECTED`
`at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.filterCheck(ObjectInputStream.java:1432) at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:2068) at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1922) at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2248) at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1757) at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:538) at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:496) at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.doDeserialize(SerializationHelper.java:225)`

After further debugging, we noticed that exception is getting thrown(In ObjectInputStream) for the attribute which is of type java.net.URI
We tried to fix this issue by applying @Basic annotation but still the error is same.
Below are some of the attributes in the domain object which is getting used in the failed test case,

```
@Id
@Column(name = "ID")
@Basic
@JdbcTypeCode(SqlTypes.VARCHAR)
private UUID id;

@Column(name = "FILE_URI")
@Basic
@Convert(converter = UriAttributeConverter.class)
@Nullable
private URI fileUri;
@Nullable
@Column(name = "APPLICATION_URI")
@Basic
@Convert(converter = UriAttributeConverter.class)
private URI applicationUri;
```

Can someone please help us with this issue with any pointers?

Answer (score 1):

As the stack indicates, Hibernate is deserializing something:

```
Caused by: java.io.InvalidClassException: filter status: REJECTED at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.filterCheck(ObjectInputStream.java:1432) 
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:2068)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1922)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2248)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1757) 
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:538) 
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:496) 
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.doDeserialize(SerializationHelper.java:225)
```

(What Hibernate is deserializing is not clear, nor why it is doing so.)

Helidon's [feature that blocks deserialization by default](https://helidon.io/docs/v3/apidocs/io.helidon.common/io/helidon/common/SerializationConfig.html) in conjunction with [Java's serialization filtering](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/core/serialization-filtering1.html#GUID-3ECB288D-E5BD-4412-892F-E9BB11D4C98A) is blocking this deserialization attempt because you have not told Helidon to permit it.